# How to detect youtube default profile thumbnail?

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

Now youtube data api V3 return channel thumbnail like
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&id=UCuLtqhcIxiZ-suKvFn72ixw&_h=1&

Thumbnail:

[image]

How detect that photo is default?I mean like in link ^^

All returned url of thumbnails are different, So if user upload image and if user did not upload youtube return same link format.

I do not want use image compare.

I do not want upload image.

I need faster way if it exist.

Comment: I didn't ever use youtube data api, but you can try using CURL or file_get_contents to get the source of the image i guess, of curse that must be your last result in case you won't find anything

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370). This is for you.

Comment: Did you already check the Youtube Data API about [thumbnails](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails)?

Comment: Yes sure.I check Youtube Data API. 
What i need check if user photo is http://i.stack.imgur.com/t9jrC.jpg

Do not use image compare. And do not upload photo. 
Youtube does not return some specific url so maybe other way..

Comment: No, if we want md5hash a file we need get conntent(download).

Answer (score 0):

So I do request for high photo image using  get_headers() and get "Content Length" so for 500 youtube channels it works fine.
But not sure use it for more